# mysql CASE SELECT Value AS ValueX(1,2,3) depending on value in another column

Tags: mysql, case

```
TopicName    | TopicUrl | MainTopicName
------------------------------
1stSubtopic  | url1     | MainOne
2ndSubtopic  | url2     | MainTwo
3rdSubtopic  | url3     | MainOne
```

As result want to get 2 php arrays

one array `$MainOne`

```
(
[TopicName1] => 1stSubtopic
[TopicUrl1] => urll
)
(
[TopicName1] => 3rdSubtopic
[TopicUrl1] => url3
)
```

another array `$MainTwo`

```
(
[TopicName2] => 2ndSubtopic
[TopicUrl2] => url2
)
```

Latter access to values like `$array_from_mysql[1]['TopicName1']`, `$array_from_mysql[2]['TopicName2']` and so on

May write two `SELECT` statements, like `SELECT TopicName, TopicUrl from table WHERE MainTopicName = ?`.

But if there are many `MainTopicName`, like MainOneHundred, then `SELECT` would not good solution.

But how to do it with `CASE` or in other way?

The below (may be) is not correct, but I just want to understand idea

```
CASE MainTopicName

WHEN MainTopicName = MainOne THEN SELECT TopicName AS TopicName1
WHEN MainTopicName = MainOne THEN SELECT TopicUrl AS TopicUrl1

WHEN MainTopicName = MainTwo THEN SELECT TopicName AS TopicName2
WHEN MainTopicName = MainTwo THEN SELECT TopicUrl AS TopicUrl2
```

What would be correct statement with `CASE` to use instead of many `SELECT` statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but maybe this is what you want:

```
SELECT MainTopicName, GROUP_CONCAT(TopicName) AS TopicNames, GROUP_CONCAT(TopicUrl) AS TopicUrls
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY MainTopicName
```

`TopicNames` and `TopicUrls` will be comma-separated lists of names and URLs.

Comment: Edited question. Mean if in column `MainTopicName` value is `MainOne`, then Select `TopicName AS TopicName1` and latter with php access to the value like `echo $array[0]['TopicName1']`

Comment: So you want a pivot table, where you get different columns in the output depending on the value in the input. See the duplicate question I just linked to.

Answer (score 0):

So you want all even or all odd rows?

You could add an `id` column as a surrogate key and then get every even or odd row:

```
SELECT TopicName, TopicUrl FROM table WHERE id % 2 = 0
```

(results in all even rows. `= 1` would give you the odd ones).